# IRC function dilemma

Tags: python, recursion, irc

[EDIT] Sorry about the title being off. I was thinking of a different problem I was having, and accidentally crossed the two.

Hi everyone, I'm writing my IRC bot skeleton in Python currently.

To explain a couple things before I ask my question, I am writing a IRC bot complete with a plug-in system that will receive signals (i.e. when a message is received, a person was seen joining a channel, ...), and to call these functions contained in the plug-in, I will be using a helper method, i.e. if we saw a message, call `sawMessage`. `sawMessage` will locate which plug-ins want to handle messages, using a `PluginManager` class, etc. I have the whole system thought out.

I also have a function for each IRC action, i.e. "doJoin", "doPart", etc. so that plug-ins can call these without me exposing my socket connection to the plug-ins directly. -- Should these functions automatically call the appropriate `sawMessage`, `sawJoin`, etc. ? Or should it be up to the plug-in to call `sawMessage` after calling `doMessage`? The reason I am asking is because if `doMessage` calls `sawMessage`, and `sawMessage` processes something that calls `doMessage`, it can end up recursing a lot before unwinding the stack.

The drawbacks of making the plug-in responsible for calling `sawMessage` to notify the other plug-ins is that the plug-in would have a choice of NOT notifying the other plug-ins, and also that if the plug-in DOES call the `sawMessage` function, the recursion issue could pop right back up.

I'm not sure how to resolve this. It seems like good practice to make `doMessage` automatically call `sawMessage` to notify other plug-ins, but there is always the possibility of a stack overflow due to recursion if the plug-in is not designed properly (i.e. not to respond to it's own messages), but if the plug-in has to call `sawMessage` anyway, the same issue is there.

Got any thoughts/opinions on this? I know it's not a straight-out question/answer, but I can't decide what to do with this. Ordinarily, if I was just writing a small bot for my own usage, I wouldn't care about a possible recursion problem. However, I am writing this for the purpose of distribution (I want this to be the next HUGE bot, just like every other IRC bot developer :D ) and I want it made properly.

Thanks!

Comment: If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea. `__import__('this')`

Comment: The next "huge" bot will be distributed. Think Skynet.

Comment: @JBernardo +1 for quoting [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @JBernardo - Sorry about the title, I accidentally crossed two problems I was having. Don't you just _love_ multitasking? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to decide between or read up more on [Publish/subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) and [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Unfortunately I don't have much experience in this area. Just happened to read a related [article](http://www.halhelms.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/10/18/Preventing-Event-Propagation-in-EventDriven-Programming) recently.

Comment: Thanks a ton :) I now created a way better system thanks to you!